# MySQL query not returning result but data exists

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `t`.* 
FROM `wp_posts` AS `t` 
LEFT JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS `age_restriction` ON `age_restriction`.`meta_key` = 'age_restriction' AND `age_restriction`.`post_id` = `t`.`ID` 
LEFT JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS `_kksr_avg` ON `_kksr_avg`.`meta_key` = '_kksr_avg' AND `_kksr_avg`.`post_id` = `t`.`ID` 
WHERE ( 
    ( `age_restriction`.`meta_value`='parental_guidance' AND `_kkr_avg`.`meta_value` BETWEEN '4.00' AND '5.00' ) AND 
    ( `t`.`post_type` = "jokes" ) AND 
    ( `t`.`post_status` IN ( "publish" ) ) 
) 
ORDER BY `t`.`menu_order`, `t`.`post_title`, `t`.`post_date` 
LIMIT 0, 15;
```

It is generated by a plugin called PODS for Wordpress, that uses the following short code to generate it:

`[pods name="jokes" where="age_restriction.meta_value='parental_guidance' AND _kkr_avg.meta_value BETWEEN '4.00' AND '5.00'" template="joke"]`

The plugin author did suggest the solution I am using above. It resulted in the error I had disappearing, but I do not get a result. There exists at least one entry that satisfy all conditions in the WHERE clause (doing a manual check in wp_posts and wp_postmeta tables), so I conclude that I am doing something wrong in the pod short code.

Things I have tried

1. `CAST()` to `DECIMAL` (no results)
2. Remove the quotes (no results)
3. Used `>= '4.00'`, but then got a MySQL syntax error (plugin author says probably because Wordpress has to parse the `>=` in the shortcode).

Any ideas, please?

*EDIT:*

If I change the query to this, without the rating, I get the result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `t`.* 
FROM `wp_posts` AS `t` 
LEFT JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS `age_restriction` ON `age_restriction`.`meta_key` = 'age_restriction' AND `age_restriction`.`post_id` = `t`.`ID` 
WHERE ( 
    ( `age_restriction`.`meta_value`='parental_guidance') AND 
    ( `t`.`post_type` = "jokes" ) AND 
    ( `t`.`post_status` IN ( "publish" ) ) 
) 
ORDER BY `t`.`menu_order`, `t`.`post_title`, `t`.`post_date` 
LIMIT 0, 15;
```

Result:

[image: Result shows if I remove the rating condition]
[image: Meta data exists for post ID 48]

Comment: Are you using a case insensitive collation? I can see three instances in that query where it may fail just because of case sensitivity.

Comment: If you run that query in your DBMS console, does it return you the expected result?

Comment: Your post should include at very least the data you expect to form a result from. My current question at this time is what value it is you expect to fall between the strings '4.00' and '5.00'

Comment: Like @Uueerdo said, to see possible errors, the dataset is really important.

Comment: Expanding on Uueerdo's comment, if you are looking for a STRING of '4.0' and '5.0', then you are not getting the NUMERIC.  If the column is of data type numeric regardless of precision, just remove the quotes around those between values.

Comment: @fubar, The query returns no results in phpMyAdmin

Comment: @Uueerdo, I am expecting to get one post from that query as it stands. Its post ID is 48, it has a rating of _kksr_avg meta_value of 5.00, and has age_restriction of 'parental_guidance'. If I remove the rating from th query, I do get the result I need.

Comment: @DRapp, please post your comment as answer, so I can accept it. After casting, I am getting the result I am looking for.

Comment: Your example query uses the string "_kkr_avg" but I only see "_kksr_avg" in the data.

Comment: @Uueerdo - apologies, yes, I did make a typo in the conversion of the query. Correcting it now. The pod now looks like this, resulting in the right data: `[pods name="jokes" where="age_restriction.meta_value='parental_guidance' AND CAST(_kksr_avg.meta_value as DECIMAL(12,2)) BETWEEN '4.00' and '5.00'" template="joke"]`

Comment: So posted as answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on Uueerdo's comment, if you are looking for a STRING of '4.0' and '5.0', then you are not getting the NUMERIC. If the column is of data type numeric regardless of precision, just remove the quotes around those between values.